# How does load balancing in Spring XD get done?

Tags: spring-xd

I've got Sring Xd running in distributed mode and now beginning to run a few JMeter tests.

My question is around how the load generated gets distributed across containers in distributed mode.

If I generate 1000 messages each for 100 users, I'd like thiis traffic to be split between two or more containers running.

Is this possible? Or does one container take on the entire load? In my current setup this is what seems to be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the stream definition? And, specifically, what is the source module?

If it's an http source, you will need a load balancer (as with any http application). You can use a hardware balancer or software, such as Apache (mod_proxy etc).

EDIT: I mentioned the deployment manifest in a comment below.

Deployment is different to stream definition. This is about how to deploy a stream that has been defined.

See the [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.M7/reference/html/#_module_deployment) for information about the deployment manifest. That link is for the M7 document, the current documentation can be found on the [Wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/XD-Distributed-Runtime) (use the browser's 'find' feature to search for `Deployment Manifest`).

For this stream...

```
xd:>stream create test1 --definition "http | transform --expression=payload.toUpperCase() | log"
```

you can get 3 instances of transform using

```
xd:>stream deploy --name test1 --properties "module.transform.count=3"
```

Comment: As of now we're working with a JMS source and dropping into log for test runs.

Comment: With a JMS source you should get load balancing automatically. The source instances are all competing consumers. Of course, you need to deploy multiple instances (using the `count` module property in the deployment manifest).

Comment: Thanks Gary. I'll try out your recommendation and update you on the progress. On a related note, do you have any benchmarks and hardware requirements typically used in production with Spring XD that could handle about 10,000 concurrent users each posting about 10 times a minute?

Comment: by deployment manifest, do you mean the modules.yml file? I looked it up on your post here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/config/modules/modules.yml but didn't find the count property. Can you clarify how I can set the count?

Comment: Thanks Gary! Now it's a lot clearer to me, will try this out right away.