# How does Spring XD load balance between instances of the same module in different containers

Tags: spring, load-balancing, spring-xd

I have read this post but it's not my case and not enough clear:

[How does load balancing in Spring XD get done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752465/how-does-load-balancing-in-spring-xd-get-done)

I have a composed job with different instances of the same sub-jobs deployed in different containers. My composed job is scheduled to run periodically. I need to know how Spring XD choose the sub-jobs instances to invoke for every new request to the composed job.

The same question for a stream triggered every X minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's handled by the transport (rabbit, redis).

Each downstream module competes for messages - with rabbit it will generally be round robin; with redis it will be more random.

Comment: Thx. Any possibility to customize that ? A customer for us asked to balance based on the container available mermory/cpu...

Comment: No; you would have to deploy different instances targeted to specific containers if you want that level of control.